# Can I use same id's for 2 elements which requires same validations in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a web project which has lots of tables. Do I need to write a separate function for each of the cells in the table for validation? Can I some how reduce the code?

Comment: Please avoid adding thankyou notes. Instead add sample code that you have problem with to get good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't use the same id for two elements. What you can do is just pass the id of the element as argument in the function you want to call to call on that element and save it as variable in your function.

See this code which I have written for you

```
<button id="1" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">B1</button>
<button id="2" onClick="`enter code here`reply_click(this.id)">B2</button>
<button id="3" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">B3</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function reply_click(clicked_id)
{
    alert(clicked_id);
}
</script>
```

By `this.id` you can send the id to the function. So no need of same ID.

Comment: so can i use a single function to implement elements requiring same validations?

Comment: Yes definitely this is how the industry works you can use this function with as many elements you want in the same page.

Comment: Thank you sir. I'm a fresher so was confused. I've been working on JS since a week so was confused.

Comment: +1. Side note: ID starting with number are not valid for pre-HTML5 HTML.

Comment: No problem dear If you want any further help you can message me on my stackoverfow profile.

Answer (score 0):

No. If 2 elements in HTML have the same ID attribute such HTML is invalid. Browsers are free to behave in whatever way they pleased in this case.

You can use "class" to share behavior/appearance between elements.

Comment: is there any thing called as getElementByClass so that i can apply operations on them in javascript?

Comment: @suhas, most people use JQuery library to deal with selecting elements, so selecting by class is generally not a problem. If you can't use other libraries and must write everything yourself Nikhil suggestion may be ok. You can't directly select by class in JavaScript, but there are plenty of samples how  to write it directly (like [this](http://www.javascriptsource.com/snippets/find-all-elements-by-class.html) ) too...

Comment: so if i add the code in the link you gave, can i use the getElementByClass method?

Comment: @suhas, it is your call... I.e. I would not be able to do so for code I write at work... and would not do for my personal code as I  use JQuery instead. I have no idea if that code is completely correct, but looked ok at a glance - try and see. But I strongly recommend looking into using JQuery as there are much more samples how to do things in JavasScript using JQuery library compared to writing all script code yourself.